# MongoDB - No server chosen with java async driver and replica set

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, driver

I have an annoying problem with the java async driver connecting to a replica set hosted on Mongodb Atlas.

I am using the below code to connect to the server through Mongo DB Java Async API 3.8.2 and 3.9.1.

I'm able to connect with the exact same connection string with the sync driver.

```
private static String str = "mongodb+srv://RWUser:****@foo-cluster-s813m.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&streamType=netty";

public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(str);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
    database.createCollection("coll", (result, t) -> latch.countDown());
    latch.await();
}
```

Here's a view of the logs :

```
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[foo-cluster-shard-00-00-s813m.mongodb.net:27017, foo-cluster-shard-00-01-s813m.mongodb.net:27017, foo-cluster-shard-00-02-s813m.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='foo-cluster-shard-0'}
janv. 18, 2019 11:31:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server foo-cluster-shard-00-00-s813m.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
janv. 18, 2019 11:31:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server foo-cluster-shard-00-01-s813m.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
janv. 18, 2019 11:31:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server foo-cluster-shard-00-02-s813m.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
janv. 18, 2019 11:31:37 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@2794eab6 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=foo-cluster-shard-00-00-s813m.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=foo-cluster-shard-00-01-s813m.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=foo-cluster-shard-00-02-s813m.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

From what I understand, the connection has been made, the cluster discovered but no primary selected from the client side.

Is there any additional property to setup ? On netty side perhaps ?
Netty stream factory is used to be able to handle SSL.

Comment: Finally found the problem... I used netty 4.1.32, adding netty in version 4.1.31 unlocks the connection

Comment: You're right, seems also to be an inconsistency in Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE between spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive and spring-boot-starter-webflux. Downgrade reactor-netty to 0.8.3.RELEASE helped

Comment: I had the same. I just updated driver to latest and it is gone